# SpringBoot initilizr and configure a rest jersey and webpage

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a class which is using @Controller annotation to identify the webpages, which is working perfect until I provide another class which is using @Component for where I am registering a Jersey. Soon as I am adding the 2nd class  with @Component annotation the 1st does not work any more. can you help me with this?
this is the @Controller

```
package com.example.demo13.newpackage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

which is working fine until I put the next class @Component which is working

```
package com.example.demo13.newpackage1;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig 
{
  public JerseyConfig() 
  {
    register(UserService.class);
  }
}
```

this is the starting class

```
package com.example.demo13;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("name = com.example.demo13.newpackage, name = com.example.demo13.newpackage1")
public class Demo13Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Demo13Application.class, args);
    }
}
```